# Generating image Preview on Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written code to get an image file and generate preview of the uploaded image.
When I read image file data and generate preview then it doesn't show preview of image, but when I put alert before binding image source this works correct.

How should I solve this issue?

Below is the code snippet

```
function changeSrc(file) {

            var reader = new FileReader();

            // array with acceptable file types
            var accept = ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/gif"];

            // if we accept the first selected file type
            if (accept.indexOf(file.files[0].type)> -1) {
                if (file.files && file.files[0]) {
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);

                   If i remove this alert then preview creates problem
                   --> ***alert(reader.result);***

                    $(#previewField).attr(src, reader.result);

                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of **`file`** object sent in the changeSrc(file) parameter? And one more thing: I think you should get error for writing `$(#previewField).attr(` rather than `$("#previewField").attr(`.

Comment: file is of type file i.e <input type="file" name="picField" onchange=" changeSrc(this); " /> .previewField syntax is correct i have added double quotes to it.